# A polynomial with nowhere surjective derivative

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, implicit-function-theorem

Let $P:\mathbb {R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb {R}^2$ be a polynomial map. It is given that the Jacobian of $P$ is everywhere not surjective. Must  the following  be true:

There exist polynomial maps $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ , $g:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^2$ such that $P= g \circ f $.

Thank you.

The reason why I put the tag abstract algebra instead of differential geometry tag only is because I am asking for the existence of morphisms which are polynomial maps and not just any morphisms in the category of smooth manifolds.

Comment: Is this a problem about `abstract-algebra`?

Comment: I guess if the  answer is yes, then I expect the same proof to apply over fields other than the real numbers too

Comment: What does it mean to say the derivatives are linearly independent? There are two first derivatives and three second derivatives and so five real numbers at every point.

Comment: Can someone edit the question to make it clear what the linear dependence condition is?

Comment: This question is confusing but the title clarifies things. "First" and "second" partial derivatives sounds like first-order and second-order at first read. So the hypothesis is that $\partial P/\partial x(a,b)$ and $\partial P/\partial y(a,b)$ are parallel vectors at each point  $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin what does the last sentence of your comment have to do with second-order derivatives?

Comment: @mathworker21: Absolutely nothing. I'm saying that I misread the problem at first. The hypothesis is that the two first-order partial derivatives are linearly dependent at each point.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. Prof.  Ted Shifrin guessed what I meant  right

Comment: A way to study the problem is to consider $P(x,y) = (P_1(x,y),P_2(x,y))$ with $P_i$ of degree(s) bounded by some constant(s); then there is a finite-dimensional affine space of coefficients of such $P$, and the Jacobian condition determines an algebraic variety. The degrees of possible $f(x,y)$ and $g_i(z)$ in $g(z) = (g_1(z),g_2(z))$ are then also restricted, and the space of coefficients of $f$ and $g$ maps into the space of coefficients of $P$ (by $P = g \circ f$); the question is whether it maps onto the variety. For low degrees (and using a CAS like SageMath) you could compute explicitly.

Comment: Differential geometry is the wrong tag, though. Multivariable analysis, perhaps. So I put the implicit function theorem. Sadly, you don't know the mapping has constant rank $1$, so that tag is probably not right, either. Algebraic geometry is actually what this is :). I certainly don't think it belongs in abstract algebra, either.

Comment: If $P = (P_1,P_2)$, then the condition that $Jac(P) = 0$ is the same as requiring $\{P_1,P_2\} = 0$, where $\{-,-\}$ is the standard Poisson structure on $\mathbb R^2$. Perhaps this formulation will help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an elementary proof.

First, some notation and terminology. Capital letters such as $F,G$ denote polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Also, $f$ (and slight variants of it, such as $\tilde{f},f_1,f_2$, etc) denotes a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, while $g,h$ (and slight variants) will denote polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[t]$. $F_x,F_y$ denote $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$, respectively. We say "$F$ is a polynomial of $f$" is there is some $g$ with $F = g\circ f$. We say that $f$ is a "minimal polynomial" if: if $f$ is a polynomial of $\tilde{f}$, then $f$ is an affine transformation of $\tilde{f}$ (i.e. $f = g\circ \tilde{f}$ implies $g(t) = at+b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$). We say "$f$ is a minimal polynomial of $F$" if $f$ is a minimal polynomial and $F$ is a polynomial of $f$.

Note that, since a square matrix is not surjective if and only if the determinant is $0$, the main problem is equivalent to: $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$ implies $F,G$ are polynomials of the same polynomial.

.

> Lemma $1$: $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$ implies there are $H^x,H^y,R^F,R^G$ with $$F_x = H^x R^F$$ $$F_y = H^y R^F$$ $$G_x = H^x R^G$$ $$G_y = H^y R^G.$$

Proof: Let $H^x = GCD(F_x,G_x), H^y = GCD(F_y,G_y)$, where the GCD is for polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ (the GCD is determined up to some multiplicative constant, but just choose arbitrary constants for now). Write $F_x = H^x R_1, F_y = H^y R_2, G_x = H^x R_3, G_y = H^y R_4$ with $GCD(R_1,R_3),GCD(R_2,R_4) = 1$. Then $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$ implies $R_1R_4 = R_2R_3$ (if $H^x \equiv 0$, then $F_x,G_x \equiv 0$ implying $F,G$ are both poly's of $y$, in which case we can let $H^x=0,H^y=1,R^F = F_y, R^G = G_y$ in the Lemma). Now, $GCD(R_1,R_3) = 1$ implies $R_1 \mid R_2$, and $GCD(R_2,R_4) = 1$ implies $R_2 \mid R_1$. So, let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $R_1 = c R_2$. Similarly, we obtain $R_3 = c'R_4$ for some $c' \in \mathbb{R}$. But $R_1R_4 = R_2R_3$ implies $c=c'$. So, we obtain $F_x = H^x cR_2, F_y = H^y R_2, G_x = H^xcR_4, G_y = H^y cR_4$. So, changing $H^x$ to $cH^x$ and letting $R^F = R_2, R^G = R_4$ gives the Lemma. $\square$

.

> Conjecture $1$: $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$ implies $(GCD(F_x,G_x))_y = (GCD(F_y,G_y))_x$.

.

Remark: The GCD's in conjecture $1$ are to be interpreted to have multiplicative constants so that they form $H^x$ and $H^y$ in Lemma $1$. In other words, conjecture $1$ is saying that $H^x_y = H^y_x$, which is equivalent to the existence of some $H$ (in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$) with $H_x = H^x$ and $H_y = H^y$ (define $H$ to be the $x$-antiderivative of $H^x$ plus a suitable function of $y$). We will prove conjecture $1$ shortly. But first:

.

> Lemma $2$: Any $H \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ has a minimal polynomial.

Let $f_0 = H$. For $n \ge 0$, if $f_n$ is not a minimal polynomial, we may let $f_{n+1}$ be such that $f_n$ is a polynomial of $f_{n+1}$ but not an affine transformation of $f_{n+1}$. Since $f_{n+1}$ has smaller degree than $f_n$ (and constant polynomials are minimal polynomials), some $f_N$ is a minimal polynomial. As $H$ is a polynomial of $f_0$ and $f_n$ is a polynomial of $f_{n+1}$ for $0 \le n \le N-1$, it follows that $H$ is a polynomial of $f_N$. $\square$

.

> Proposition $1$: Conjecture $1$ implies the following. For any $F,H$ for which there is some $R$ with $F_x = H_x R$, $F_y = H_y R$, it holds that $F$ is a polynomial of any minimal polynomial of $H$.

Proof: We induct on $\deg(F)$ (i.e. largest degree of monomial in $F$, where $\deg(x^ay^b) := a+b$). The proposition is trivial if $\deg(F) = 0$, i.e. if $F$ is constant. So suppose $\deg(F) \ge 1$, and fix a minimal polynomial $f^H$ of $H$. Note that $F_{xy} = H_{xy}R+H_xR_y$ and $F_{yx} = H_{yx}R+H_yR_x$. Since $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$ and $H_{xy} = H_{yx}$, we see that $H_xR_y = H_yR_x$. By Lemma $1$ and conjecture $1$, there are $Q,T,S$ with $H_x = Q_xT, H_y = Q_y T, R_x = Q_x S, R_y = Q_y S$. If $\deg(H) = \deg(F)$, then going back to $F_x = H_xR, F_y = H_y R$, we see $H = F$ and we are of course done. And of course we have $\deg(R) \le \deg(F_x) < \deg(F)$. Therefore, we can apply the inductive hypothesis to deduce that $H$ and $R$ are polynomials of any minimal polynomial of $Q$. Let $f$ be any minimal polynomial of $Q$, and say $H = g_1\circ f, R = g_2\circ f$. Then $F_x = H_xR = (g_1'\circ f)f_x(g_2\circ f) = (g_1'g_2 \circ f)f_x$ implies $F = (\int g_1'g_2)\circ f$ up to a polynomial in $y$, but then $F_y = H_y R$ implies that polynomial in $y$ is $0$, so $F$ is a polynomial of $f$.

But we want $F$ a polynomial of $f^H$. It suffices, then, to show that $f^H$ is an affine transformation of $f$. To do this, write $H = g_3 \circ f^H$. Recalling that we had $H = g_1\circ f$, we see $(g_3'\circ f^H)f^H_x = H_x = (g_1'\circ f)f_x$ and $(g_3'\circ f^H)f^H_y = H_y = (g_1'\circ f)f_y$. These equalities imply $f^H_xf_y = f^H_yf_x$, so by Lemma $1$ and conjecture $1$ once again, there are $\tilde{Q},\tilde{T},\tilde{S}$ with $f^H_x = \tilde{Q}_x\tilde{T}, f^H_y = \tilde{Q}_y\tilde{T}, f_x = \tilde{Q}_x\tilde{S}, f_y = \tilde{Q}_y\tilde{S}$. Since $\deg(f^H),\deg(f) \le \deg(H) < \deg(F)$, the inductive hypothesis implies that $f^H,f$ are polynomials of any minimal polynomial of $\tilde{Q}$. Say $\tilde{f}$ is a minimal polynomial of $\tilde{Q}$. Then, by definition, $f^H,f$ are affine transformations of $\tilde{f}$ and thus $f^H,f$ are affine transformations of each other. $\square$

.

Remark: Minimal polynomials are actually unique. I know this, since the truth of the main problem easily implies it, and we know the truth of the main problem from Stefano (or from this whole answer). However, I couldn't use this secret uniqueness, since I don't want a circular proof, of course. I sort of established the uniqueness of the minimal polynomial of $H$ in the proof above, but I needed an inductive statement to work with.

.

> Conjecture $1$ implies the main problem.

Proof: By Lemma $1$ and conjecture $1$, $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$ implies there are $H,R^F,R^G$ as in Lemma $1$. Take any minimal polynomial $f$ of $H$. Then proposition $1$ implies that $F,G$ are polynomials of $f$. $\square$

.

Remark: The proof just given shows why it is important that proposition $1$ cannot just be "$F$ is a polynomial of some minimal polynomial of $H$" (which is easier to prove), since we needed the same polynomial for both $F$ and $G$.

Now on to the proof of Conjecture $1$. First, a lemma. For $F,G \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$, we denote $GCD_{x,y}(F,G)$ to be the GCD of $F,G$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ (i.e. the GCD we've been talking about), and $GCD_x(F,G)$ to be the GCD in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ of $F$ and $G$ viewed as polynomials in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$. Note the latter is determined up to a multiplicative factor of a rational polynomial in $y$.

.

> Lemma 3: For any $F,G \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$, $GCD_x(F,G) = GCD_{x,y}(F,G)$, up to a rational polynomial of $y$.

Proof: Let $H = GCD_{x,y}(F,G)$. Then there are $R^F,R^G,Q^F,Q^G \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ with $F = H R^F, G = H R^G$, and $GCD_{x,y}(R^F,R^G) = 1$. We may view the equations $F = HR^F, G = HR^G$ in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$. If $GCD_x(R^F,R^G) = 1$, then we're done, so suppose otherwise; that is, there are $h,f,g \in (\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ with $R^F = hf$ and $R^G = hg$, and $\deg_{(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]}(h) \ge 1$. Let $l_h,l_f,l_g \in \mathbb{R}[y]$ denote the lcm of the denominators of the coefficients of $h,f,g$, respectively. Then, $l_hl_f R^F = (l_h h)(l_f f)$ and $l_hl_g R^G = (l_h h)(l_g g)$. For each irreducible element $q$ of $\mathbb{R}[y]$ dividing $l_h$, since $l_hl_fR^F, l_h h$, and $l_f f$ are in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, we may reduce the equation $l_hl_f R^F = (l_h h)(l_f f)$ mod $q$ to see that $q$ divides each coefficient of $l_f f$. Repeating this argument allows us to write $R^F = \frac{l_h h}{l_f}\frac{l_f f}{l_h}$, with $\frac{l_h h}{l_f}, \frac{l_f f}{l_h} \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Similarly, we have $R^G = \frac{l_h h}{l_g}\frac{l_g g}{l_h}$. Therefore, if we let $L = lcm(l_f,l_g)$ (in $\mathbb{R}[y]$), we see $R^F = \frac{l_h h}{L}\frac{L}{l_f}\frac{l_f f}{l_c}$ and $R^G = \frac{l_h h}{L}\frac{L}{l_g}\frac{l_g g}{l_h}$, implying $\frac{l_h h}{L}$ divides both $R^F$ and $R^G$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, implying it must be constant, implying $h$ is solely a function of $y$, yielding the desired contradiction. $\square$

.

> Proposition $2$: For $F,G,Q,R^x,R^y \in (\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ satisfying $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$, and $F_x = QG_x+R^x$ and $F_y = QG_y+R^y$ with $\deg(R^x) < \deg(G_x), \deg(R^y) < \deg(G_y)$, it holds that $R^x_y = R^y_x$.

Remark: Here, just to clarify, the degree of a polynomial in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x] = c_nx^n+\dots+c_1x+c_0$ with $c_n,\dots,c_0 \in \mathbb{R}(y)$ and $c_n \not = 0$ is $n$.

.

> Proposition $2$ implies Conjecture $1$.

Proof: The division algorithm in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ implies there are $Q^x,Q^y,R^x,R^y \in (\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ with $F_x = Q^xG_x+R^x, F_y = Q^yG_y+R^y$, and $\deg(R^x) < \deg(G_x), \deg(R^y) < \deg(G_y)$. Multiplying the equations gives $Q^y F_xG_y +F_xR^y = Q^xG_xF_y + R^xF_y$. Therefore, using $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$, we obtain $(Q^y-Q^x)F_xG_y = R^xF_y-R^yF_x$. Since $\deg(R^x) < \deg(G_x)$, $\deg(R^xF_y) < \deg(G_xF_y) = \deg(F_xG_y)$, and since $\deg(R^yF_x) < \deg(G_yF_x)$, we must have $Q^y = Q^x$. Denote each by $Q$. Then, proposition $2$ implies $R^x_y = R^y_x$. This allows us to take $R$ such that $R_x = R^x$ and $R_y = R^y$. Now just repeat this whole process with $(G,R)$ instead of $(F,G)$, which we can do since $F_xG_y = F_yG_x$ implies $G_xR_y = G_yR_x$. Euclid's algorithm says that if we keep doing this process, we eventually end up with remainders $GCD_x(F_x,G_x)$ and $GCD_x(F_y,G_y)$, so a final application of proposition $2$, together with Lemma 3, finishes the job. $\square$

.

Remark: It should be emphasized that the $Q$ and $R$ obtained in the above process can be in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ and not $(\mathbb{R}[y])[x]$ (e.g. $x = \frac{1}{y}(xy+1)-\frac{1}{y}$), which is why we've been talking about $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$. However, this distinction doesn't matter for any of the proofs. Also, part of the statement of proposition $2$ and implicit in part of the proof just given is that the exact value of $GCD_x(F_x,G_x)$ or $GCD_y(F_y,G_y)$ (i.e., whatever specific multiplicative factor of a rational polynomial in $y$ we have) does not matter.

.

> Proof of Proposition $2$

Note $F_{xy} = Q_yG_x+QG_{xy}+R^x_y$ and $F_{yx} = Q_xG_y+QG_{yx}+R^y_x$, so, since $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$ and $G_{xy} = G_{yx}$, it suffices to show $Q_xG_y = Q_yG_x$. Write $F(x) = a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0, G(x) = b_mx^m+\dots+b_1x+b_0, Q(x) = c_{n-m}x^{n-m}+\dots+c_1x+c_0$. Then, $$F_x = na_nx^{n-1}+\dots+2a_2x+a_1 \mspace{15mm} F_y = a_n'x^n+\dots+a_1'x+a_0'$$ $$G_x = mb_mx^{m-1}+\dots+2b_2x+b_1 \mspace{15mm} G_y = b_m'x^m+\dots+b_1'x+b_0'$$ $$Q_x = (n-m)c_{n-m}x^{n-m-1}+\dots+2c_2x+c_1 \mspace{5mm} Q_y = c_{n-m}'x^{n-m}+\dots+c_1'x+c_0'.$$ Now fix $k \ge m-1$. That the coefficient of the term $x^k$ in $F_x$ is the same as that in $QG_x$ gives $$(k+1)a_{k+1} = \sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} c_j(k-j+1)b_{k-j+1},$$ where I assumed $k \ge n-m$ for ease (if $k < n-m$, the upper bound on $j$ is $k$ instead of $n-m$, but this doesn't meaningfully change the argument at all). Differentiating with respect to $y$ gives $$(k+1)a_{k+1}' = \sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} \left[c_j'(k-j+1)b_{k-j+1}+c_j(k-j+1)b_{k-j+1}'\right].$$ Now, $Q_xG_y$ and $Q_yG_x$ have the same the coefficient of the $x^k$ term if and only if $$\sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} jc_jb_{k-j+1}' = \sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} c_j'(k-j+1)b_{k-j+1}.$$ Comparing with the last centered equation, we wish to show $$\sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} jc_jb_{k-j+1}' = (k+1)a_{k+1}'-\sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} c_j(k-j+1)b_{k-j+1}',$$ which is equivalent to $$\sum_{k-m+1 \le j \le n-m} c_jb_{k-j+1}' = a_{k+1}'.$$ And this is true, since the coefficient of the term $x^{k+1}$ in $F_y$ is the same as that in $QG_y$. $\square$

Comment: Hello. In lemma 3,  why do we have $Q^F R^F+Q^G R^G=1$ in $R[x,y]$ (which is only a ufd and not a pid). I feel lemma 3 should be true nonetheless. I ll continue finishing ur proof anyways

Comment: @Amr Thanks for pointing that out! An example of how the proof is wrong if $F=x,G=y$ (can't write $1$ as a linear combination of $R^F = x$ and $R^G = y$). However, not only was the proof of Lemma 3 wrong, but also the statement of it was more non-well-defined that I initially realized. The gcd in $(\mathbb{R}(y))[x]$ is well-defined up to multiplication by rational polynomial in $y$, whereas the gcd in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is not (e.g. $GCD_{x,y}(y,y) = y$, up to a multiplicative real number, whereas you can say $GCD_x(y,y) = 1$). The nice thing is that multiplicative factors of rational

Comment: polynomials in $y$ do not affect the later part of the proof (see the comments I added to my answer). I also added a (hopefully correct) proof for Lemma 3. It is easy to see that the gcd in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is the same as the gcd in $(\mathbb{R}[y])[x]$, so all we need is a "Gauss Lemma for GCDs". I don't know if such a thing already exists and is popular (I haven't done algebra in years), but the proof I came up with is very similar to the proof of Gauss's Lemma about irreducibility of polynomials over a ring and its ring of fractions. Hopefully all is resolved now.

Comment: Hii, thank you for your edits. yes I expected lemma 3 to remain correct because of a gauss lemma/ content type argument. I ll finish reading the proof tonight once I m back home.

Comment: I think the notion of gauss lemma applies for polynomials over  any UFD. As R[x,y] is naturally isomorphic to R[x][y] and R[x] is a UFD, hence one can use gauss lemma. Hopefully I m correct too, because I also didn't do algebra in years. What' your specialization by the way ?

Comment: @Amr Well, Gauss's lemma doesn't say anything about gcd's (as far as I am aware), but rather concerns reducibility of polynomials. Thanks for reading through everything. I do a mixture of analysis and combinatorics (e.g. additive combinatorics). What about you?

Comment: @Amr is this over?

Comment: Heey mathworker.  I m very embarrassed to not finish  verifying your proof yet. It's my fault. I  appologize and am really ashamed of my poor time management in dealing with ur question and in dealing with life in general. So let me break the habit and make a FINAL promise of getting this thing done in the next 24 hours starting now.

Comment: Your solution is imortant to me because it is based on mathematics which I m able to understand and because I think it will allow me to give a different proof to sards theore

Comment: Thats sweet. I failed to consider gcd (s), in my attempts. Combining gcd (s) with double partial derivatives seems to be what I missed.

Comment: I can't award a bounty using my phone, but it's the least I can do to say thank you for the time you spent in finding the right sequence of lemmas. Btw, I  have the trivial comment that H should be nonconstant in prop 1. There will actually be a division by zero somewhere in your proof of prop 1 if h is constant. Another trivial comment , in your proof that prop 2 implies conjecture 1 there is a less than or equal sign which I think should be changed to strict inequality

Comment: I mean 99% of my time was spent on proving conjecture 1. Deciding to use division algorithm was the key insight for me. But even something like the proof of proposition 2 took several hours to find. Working with $R^x_y$ and $R^y_x$ makes the computations unbearable; everything worked out so nicely ignoring them (as I showed). Also, the form of proposition 1 was tricky; like I mentioned, you need to have the conclusion of being a polynomial of *any* minimal polynomial of $H$, and to prove it, you needed to be clever with induction. Well, thanks for reading the solution. I had fun with all the

Comment: time I spent on this problem. I am very interested in the different proof of sards theorem you are going after... Are you thinking about publishing it?

Comment: I don't see why $H$ should be nonconstant in prop 1, i.e., prop 1 is true if $H$ is constant. You can just assume $H$ is nonconstant throughout the proof. thank you for your second 'trivial comment', fixed.

Comment: You are right, H need not be nonconstant in prop 1 (my fault). The website is asking me to wait for 23 hours before awarding a bounty.

Comment: Its not necessarily a novel proof of sard's theorem. It's a proof I came up with after challenging myself to prove sard's theorem without looking at the book's proof. It seemed to work assuming we have this abstract algebra fact (I will need a more general version of it with $P:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which I could prove by trying to mimic your proof). I will try to write a  sketch of the proof.

Comment: @Amr Thanks a lot for the bounty. I appreciate it. Let me know if you encounter any issues generalizing the proof to $P: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. I'm not sure how "nice" the equation '$F_xG_y = F_yG_x$' needed to be; we surely used it a lot. Anyways, let me know once you write the sketch of a proof of Sard's theorem, even with the general version of the abstract algebra fact as a blackbox. You can either post it here or email it to me (or neither); I'm interested.

Comment: Thank you so much. unfourtanetly I realized that my idea of using your result to prove sard's theorem no longer works for some technical challenges. A special case of my idea can be made to work , but it does not make use of your result. But then again, your result is interesting on its own right.

Comment: @Amr Alright. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hello, Please Check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture. They say even the 2 variables case is still unsolved

Comment: @Amr Yep! I am really curious if the question you asked has been considered before. I don't see any way to use the methods in this answer to attack the Jacobian conjecture. I've heard the conjecture is very famous though and has been worked on by many, many people.

Answer (score 14):

As a disclaimer, I will follow an "algebraic geometer" approach. Thus, all the morphisms will essentially be polynomials (or rational functions).

To be short, my answer is "yes". The exaplanation is a bit long though.

Let me start with a remark on your comment about the argument working over different fields. Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (e.g., $\mathbb C$), there are tools that replace the implicit function theorem. That is, if we have a morphism between smooth varieties, the dimension of the image should match the maximal rank of the jacobian. In particular, in your case, the image of $P$ will be either a curve or a point (we know it by base changing to $\mathbb C$, as $\mathbb R$ is not algebraically closed). On the other hand, this is not true over fields of characteristic $p > 0$. In particular, the Frobenius morphism from a variety to itself (so, from $k^2$ to itself, if $k$ is a field of positive characteristic) is a dominant morphism (that is, the image is dense. It is surjective if $k$ is perfect) whose differential is identically zero. Indeed, this morphism is defined as $x \mapsto x^p$, and its differential is $p \cdot x^{p-1}dx$, which is $0$ as $p=0$. Thus, if we take the Frobenius for $k^2$ with $k$ a field of positive characteristic, the claim in your question does not hold.

Now, let me assume that we are working over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. In particular, we may assume that $k=\mathbb C$. We will use this case to deduce something about the case $k = \mathbb R$.

Now, by the discussion above, we know that the image has dimension 0 or 1. If it has dimension 0, then your claim follows, as we can take $f \colon k^2 \rightarrow k$ and $g \colon k \rightarrow k^2$ to be suitable constant polynomials. Thus, I will assume that the image has dimension 1.

By the above reductions, we know that the image of $P : k^2 \rightarrow k^2$ is a curve $C$. This curve $C$ may be singular. On the other hand, as $k^2$ is smooth, we know that $k^2 \rightarrow C$ factors as $f \colon k^2 \rightarrow T$ and $g \colon T \rightarrow C \subset k^2$, where $T$ is smooth (here $T$ is the normalization of $C$). Now, as $k^2$ is a rational variety (it can be compactified to be $\mathbb P ^2_k$, the projectiva plane over $k$), $T$ is unirational (essentially by definition of unirational). As $T$ has dimension 1, the solution to the Lüroth problem in dimension 1, it follows that $T$ is rational. That is, $T$ is an open subset of the projective line $\mathbb P ^1_k$.
Furthermore, as $T$ maps to $k^2$, it can not be compact. Thus, $T$ is an open subset of the affine line $k$. As the topology I am using is the Zariski topology, it means that $T$ is $k$ with possibly a finite number of points removed.
By the comment of David Speyer below, we can then conclude that $T=k$. Indeed, if $T$ was strictly contained in $k$, $T$ would admit non-constant units in its coordinate ring. Then, these functions would pull back to $k^2$ along the morphism $k^2 \rightarrow T$, providing some non-constant units in $k[x,y]$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, to summarize, we got a morphism $f \colon k^2 \rightarrow k$, and a morphism $g \colon k \rightarrow C \subset k^2$. As we are dealing with algebraic varieties, and as $f$ has domain $k^2$ and target $k$, $f$ is a polynomial. Similarly, $g$ is a polynomial too.

Now, let's go back to your $P$ defined over $\mathbb R$. By base change to $\mathbb C$, we can regard $P$ as a morphism $P_\mathbb{C} \colon \mathbb C ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb C ^2$ (basically, you keep the same polynomials, and input complex values). As the image of $P_\mathbb{C}$ has dimension 1, so does the image of $P$. Furthermore, the image of $P_\mathbb{C}$ is obtained from the image of $P$ by "base change to $\mathbb{C}$". This guarantees that what we concluded over $\mathbb C$ still holds over $\mathbb R$.

Let me conclude with a remark. We heavily relied on the fact that we were interested in $k^2$. This guaranteed that the image of $P$ was a point or a curve. To treat the curve case, we used Lüroth's theorem. This guarantees that every unirational curve is rational. This is not true in higher dimension: it is still true for surfaces in characteristic zero, but it fails even over $\mathbb C$ in higher dimension. Thus, I do not expect this argument to generalize for morphisms $P \colon k^n \rightarrow k^n$ with $dP$ never surjective.

Comment: what's an example of polynomial $f$, rational non-polynomial $g$ with $g\circ f$ polynomial?

Comment: I claim $T$ has exactly one point removed (over $\mathbb{C}$). You already showed $T$ is not all of $\mathbb{P}^1$. If $T$ were missing two points, then there would be nonconstant units on $T$, which would pull back to nonconstant units on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you, I will update the answer with your remark. I believe this should imply the statement over $\mathbb R$ too. Is that right, or am I missing something (I am always dubious over non-closed fields)?

Comment: @Stefano I think you are right. I haven't checked through everything carefully -- I had this question marked with the intention to think through the details and leave an answer very similar to yours if no one got there first, but I am very glad you did the work.

Comment: @mathworker21 The trivial counterexample is when $f$ is a constant polynomial. Of course, here we are thinking of $f$ mapping to an open set of the domain of $g$. On the top of my head, I do not have an answer for this case, but I would not be surprised it can not happen.

Comment: I don't have enough algebraic geometry background to understand your answer. Your answer is still useful as it informs me that this question possibly needs techniques outside the scope of abstract algebra. I still feel that a an algebraic proof in characteristic 0 might be possible. If I ever succeed in doing that, I will post it here.

Comment: @Amr I understand that this is not a very accessible answer without some background in algebraic geometry. Definitely, I agree that one can get an answer using algebra, just because all of the above has a counterpart in commutative algebra. On the other hand, I am a bit skeptical one can get a low technology proof with basic algebra. More precisely, I guess you can avoid some of the above steps, but I'd definitely recommend looking into Lüroth's theorem.

Comment: @Stefano see my elementary solution below.

Comment: Hello, Please check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture. They say even the 2 variables case is still unsolved